# remove from collection bind to remove from view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection and when I remove a model from the collection, I want it to remove the item from a list in the view.

My collection is pretty basic

```
MyApp.Collections.CurrentEvents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyApp.Models.Event
});
```

and in my views I have

```
MyApp.Views.CurrentEventItem = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: 'div.current_event',

   initialize: function(){
        event = this.model;
        _.bindAll(this, "remove");
        MyApp.CurrentEvents.bind('remove',this.remove); //the collection holding events

     this.render();
  },

   // yeah, yeah, render stuff here

 remove: function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(this.el).unbind();
    $(this.el).remove();
  }
});
```

when I remove the model from the collection, it triggers the remove function, but the view is still on the page. 
In the console, I can see the model, but I believe the model should have an 'el', but it doesn't.

My container code is

```
MyApp.Views.CurrentEventsHolder = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div#currentHolder',

    initialize: function(){
           MyApp.CurrentEvents = new MyApp.Collections.CurrentEvents();
           MyApp.CurrentEvents.bind('new', this.add);
   },
   add: function(){  
        var add_event = new MyApp.Views.CurrentEventItem(added_event);
        $('div#currentHolder').append(add_event.el);

     }
});
```

for some reason in the `add` method I can't seem to use the `$(this.el)` before the append, though I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: You output `$(this.el)` from within the `remove` function? The way your function is written, it should be removing *all* the event views when `collection.remove` happens.

Comment: Why aren't you using `this.bind` in your initialize method? What happens if you set a breakpoint in the remove method and manually type in the `$(this.el).remove()`

Comment: @JoshLeitzel why should it be removing all of my views? I believe backbone knows which model has been deleted and should remove only that one.

Comment: @tkone I'll try using this.bind, but it will have to wait until I get to work tomorrow morning. I have no idea how to manually type `$(this.el).remove` into a breakpoint. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: In chrome or safari launch the web inspector and go to the scripts tab. Click on the line number next to the place you want to pause script execution. See this: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/scripts-breakpoints.html  In Firefox you'll need to install firebug and then read this: http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html. It allows you to stop code execution at an explicit point and check the current execution context and stack, as well as the values of any variables and attributes available within the execution context.

Comment: @pedalpete I've posted a complete response regarding that problem. If that does not fix your original problem, let me know and I'll be happy to look at it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM:** `MyApp.CurrentEvents.bind('remove',this.remove);`

This triggers the `remove()` function every time **any** model is deleted from the collection.

This means that anytime a model is deleted, **all** the `CurrentEventItem` view instances **will be deleted.**

**Now, about the view still being on the page:**

It must have something to do with the way you appended/added/html-ed the view in the page. Check your other views, maybe if you have a `CurrentEventsContainer` view of some sort, check your code from there *because with your current code, it does delete the view*, albeit, *all of them* though.

**RECOMMENDED FIX:**

change your bindings to:

```
this.model.bind('remove',this.remove);
```

and make sure that when you instantiate it, pass on the `model` so that *each view will have a corresponding model to it like so:*

```
//...
addAllItem: function(){ 
      _.each(this.collection, this.addOneItem())
},
addOneItem: function(model){
      var currentEventItem = new MyApp.Views.CurrentEventItem({model:model});
      //...more code..
}
//...
```

This makes things a lot easier to manage in my opinion.

**UPDATE (from your updated question)**

The reason you aren't able to use `this.el` is because you haven't passed the right context into the `add()` function. You need to add `_.bindAll(this,'add')` in your `initialize()` function to pass the right context, therefore making your `this` correct, allowing you to use `this.el` within the `add` function. Also, change your code to this:

`MyApp.CurrentEvents.bind('new', this.add, this);` this passes the right context. Also, why not use `add` instead as an event?

Comment: You were correct Jan, I had a problem with the way I was adding the currentEvent in my currentEventHolder. Though I still have the same issue, I'm updating the question.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it helps! Let me know any other questions.

Comment: Thanks Jan Carlo, I always get confused with the `this` context and even after reading Yehuda Katz's blog, I still haven't got a grasp of it. `add` is an event, but I have it in the container for some reason, I'll move it into the child.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing what I said in the comments, the way you've implemented this right now will remove *all* the `CurrentEventItem` views from the page when *any* of them is removed from the collection. The reason for this is the following:

```
MyApp.CurrentEvents.bind('remove',this.remove);
```

What this essentially says is, "every time the `remove` event is triggered on the collection, call `this.remove`." So, every time you instantiate one of these views, you're also telling the collection to remove *that* view when the collection triggers a `remove` event. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/pGjds/1/) to show you the problem.

You're right that Backbone knows which model has been removed from a collection, but you're not taking advantage of that. You can do that like so:

```
  removeFromView: function(model) {
    // Check to make sure the model removed was this.model
    if (model.cid === this.model.cid) {
      $(this.el).unbind();
      $(this.el).remove();
    }
  }
```

See how this minor adjustment changes the behavior? Check it out in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/H9s9T/1/).

If you follow this pattern, you should see the proper views being removed.

Comment: thanks Josh, from my understanding, I shouldn't need to check cid against the model (unless you can explain to me why this is necessary). I believe the view is supposed to know which item is being removed. Though you are right about the `.bind`, that has not resolved the problem.